# Remote IP in Bun.serve (no framework)

Tags: http, bun

I'm using [bun](https://bun.sh/) v0.1.7 (NOT nodejs), I'm trying the built-in basic http server without any other framework:

```js
export default {
  port: 3000,
  fetch(request: Request) {    
    const remoteIp = request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for') || 'UNKNOWN';
    return new Response(remoteIp);
  },
};
```

Can I get the remote IP from the client when I'm not using any proxies ?

I've tried `request.connenction.remoteAddress`, `request.socket...` But nothing seems to be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bun `v1.0.4` release [implements `server.requestIP()`](https://bun.sh/blog/bun-v1.0.4#implement-server-requestip).

Quoting from the release notes:

> With `#6165`, the IP address of a given Request can now be retrieved
> using `server.requestIP()`.
>
> ```
> Bun.serve({
>   port: 3000,
>   handler: (req, res) => {
>     console.log(server.requestIP(req));
>   },
> });
> ```
>
> This does not read headers like `X-Forwarded-For` or `X-Real-IP`. It
> simply returns the IP address of the socket, which may correspond to
> the IP address of a proxy.
>
> We've also added support to `node:http` for getting the socket
> address. `net.Socket().address` now returns an object with address,
> port, and family properties.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (v 0.1.7), the Bun.serve Request object doesn't add anything to the Request object beyond the standard. According to [Discord question](https://discord.com/channels/876711213126520882/1006494319697461298)

However, It's possible that in a future the Request object was extended by Bun.serve with additional data like remoteIp, cookies, etc. Just like node http server does.

Answer (score 0):

The example from the quoted docu ([This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77257268/15354708)) does not work as is.
The implementation changed over versions and this code snippet is also incomplete and semantically incorrect.

#### Solution

This is a working codesnippet (written in **Typescript**) (Bun version 1.0.7 was used in my test):

```js
const server = Bun.serve({
  port: 8080,
  async fetch(request: Request) { // async is optional, depending on your usecase
    let sourceIP = this.requestIP(request) // using this instead of server as server is not yet initialized and thus does not work.

    const response = new Response(`Your Request came from ${sourceIP?.family} ${sourceIP?.address} on Port ${sourceIP?.port}\n`);

    return response;
  }
});
```